# Environment variables set in CMakeLists.txt or exported not propagated to build tools

Tags: macos, cmake, uic

I am trying to make the Qt build folder portable so that it can be built on one machine and shared with others. I'm running into an issue on macOS actually using the Qt uic tool in CMake with an error like this:

```
dyld[74739]: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
Referenced from: /path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/bin/uic
Reason: tried: '/path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/bin/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore' (no such file), '/original_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore' (no such file)
... (some other paths)
```

`otool -l /path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/bin/uic` shows me that the path to the framework in the original Qt build folder is hardcoded. I can get `uic` to run correctly if I set `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/lib` but I can't get this to work in the actual CMake build. I've tried both of the following:

`export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/lib cmake --build BUILD --target app`

as well as setting the environment in the CMakeLists.txt file:

`set(ENV{DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH} /path_to_moved_Qt_build_folder/qtbase/lib)`

I've also tried setting the Libraries path in qt.conf but this also does not seem to affect how uic runs.

But in both cases when running my build I am getting the original error again. How can I get this variable exported so uic will use it?

Answer (score 1):

You tried to do this with `set(ENV{...} ...)`, but that won't affect the build. See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable), which state:

> This command affects only the current CMake process, not the process from which CMake was called, nor the system environment at large, nor the environment of subsequent build or test processes.

If you want to set an environment variable for a build command, you can use [the CMake `env` commandline command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-env), like `cmake -E env VAR_NAME=VALUE -- cmake --build ...`. Or if the build tool accepts other forms of setting the variable you want to set (such as Make), you can pass them to the underlying build tool at the end of the `cmake --build` command after a `--` ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake--build-0)). Ex. `cmake --build ... -- VAR_NAME=VALUE`.

If you are using [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), configure, build, test, and package presets all have a `environment` property that you can use, and build, test, and package presets also have a `inheritConfigureEnvironment` property. See also the preset macro docs for `$env{<variable-name>}` and `$penv{<variable-name>}`.

If you are using the VS Code CMake Tools extension without CMake presets, see also [these settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings): `cmake.environment`, `cmake.configureEnvironment`, `cmake.buildEnvironment`, `cmake.testEnvironment`, and `cmake.buildToolArgs`.

Note: your attempt to export an environment variable looks wrong. I think you either meant to use a shell syntax like [`VAR_NAME=VALUE <command>`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126938/550426), or put a semicolon or `&&` between the `export` command and the command you want to run with the exported variable.

Comment: I actually use CMake Tools and none of the cmake environment variants worked for me (though `"cmake.builtToolArgs": ["MYVAR=MYVAL"]` works).

CMake presets might work, but I'm not using them yet. I know using running a cmake command line command to run cmake doesn't work (just tried it).

Comment: @TimothyRiley 1) updated answer to add `cmake.buildToolArgs`. 2) "_I know using running a cmake command line command to run cmake doesn't work_" What exactly did you try? Can you show me?

Comment: I tried running `cmake -E -- cmake` and got the following output:

`
CMake Error: cmake version 3.26.0
Usage: cmake -E <command> [arguments...]
Available commands:
  capabilities              - Report capabilities built into cmake in JSON format
  cat [--] <files>...       - concat the files and print them to the standard output
  chdir dir cmd [args...]   - run command in a given directory
  compare_files [--ignore-eol] file1 file2
`

.. and a bunch more. I would expect the default cmake usage prompt. I see similar results with other programs.

Comment: @TimothyRiley why are you doing `cmake -E -- cmake` when I told you to do `cmake -E VAR_NAME=VALUE -- cmake --build ...`?

Comment: The env variable assignment present or not, and cmake args present or not is irrelevant.

Did you try it yourself?

Comment: @TimothyRiley yes and it worked just fine. Ex. (I did) `cmake -E env FOO=BAR -- cmake --build build`. I have CMake 3.26.3. Oh. I see now. I wrote it wrong in my post. Fixing now. Really sorry about that. Can you give the fixed version a try?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - for me, CMake is generating a Makefile, so I found that you can pass environment variables to it, for example:

`make target FOO=BAR`

If using CMake itself to build, then do this:

`cmake --build BUILD --target target -- FOO=BAR`